# Hubot. Get the mentioned user's email in Slack

Tags: slack-api, hubot

I'm writing a Script for Hubot using the Slack API

How can I get the mentioned user's email (@ben for example) from a message?

I've figured out I can do something like:

```
user.profile.email
```

To get the current user, but I'm not sure about searching for others or getting a profile based on a mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the email for a Slack user you need to

1. Retrieve list of all users from the Slack API with [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)
2. Browse through the list and match by user name or user ID

Note that your access token needs both the `users:read` and `users:read.email` scopes in order to retrieve that information. See also [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) for more info about scopes and [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list#email_addresses) for detail on email address access.